# Cannot find module .next/server/font-manifest.json'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, deployment

This is driving me nuts, I'm trying to deploy nextjs app with server rending.
The app is built using Azure Pipelines and uploaded to the production server (linux box).

Here is my config:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  output: 'standalone',
  optimizeFonts: false, // true or false doesn't make any difference
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

My build agent runs:

1. `yarn install`
2. `yarn build` does `next build`
3. zips `/.next` directory to the artefact
4. uploads artefact

Then the pipeline continues and uploads and unzips my artefact on production server.
Where I do the following:

1. `cd :/var/apps/myapp/standalone`
2. `yarn start` which does `next start`

What I get is this:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/var/apps/myapp/standalone/.next/server/font-manifest.json'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Me too. I did not configure `output: 'standalone'`, but got the same error, and then checked the `.next/server/` directory and found that the `next-font-manifest.json` file existed, so I'd renamed it to `font-manifest.json` . Now It's worked.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation mentions that once project is built it is necessary to copy these two:

```
# SM.Web is my root of the web project

cp -R src/SM.Web/public "src/SM.Web/.next/standalone/public"

cp -R src/SM.Web/.next/static" src/SM.Web/.next/standalone/.next/static"
```

and create artefact liek this:

```
zip src/SM.Web/.next/standalone SM.Web.zip
```

I described the entire process here:

https://dev.to/kedzior_io/deploy-self-hosted-nextjs-application-with-net-api-43p8